# How to fix this error with Android and Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I try to write code to switch activity from `MainActivity` to `SecondActivity`. And in `SecondActivity`, I initialize a `FirebaseFirestore` object in `onCreate()` method. I use a button in activity_main.xml to switch from `MainActivity` to `SecondActivity`. However, my app crashes. It did not go to the SecondActivity after I clicked the button. I really need help to solve this problem. And I need to write some data to firebase through `FirebaseFirestore` object in `Secondctivity`.

I think the main reason for this crash is I initialized `FirebaseFirestore` object in `onCreate()` method. Once I commented out this initialization, crash disappeared.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name;
    EditText age;
    private static final String TAG = "SecondActivity";
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second2);
        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        age = findViewById(R.id.age);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Toast.makeText(this, "testing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }
}
```

The errors are the following.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.hw1, PID: 25341
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hw1/com.example.hw1.SecondActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not
>   initialized in this process com.example.hw1. Make sure to call
>   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
>
> at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>
> at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>
> at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not
>   initialized in this process com.example.hw1.  Make sure to call
>   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
>
> at
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:245)
>
> at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:70)
>
> at com.example.hw1.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:37)
>
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
>
> at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>
> at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>
> at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>
> at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>
> I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=16KB, data=20KB
>
> After code cache collection, code=16KB, data=20KB
>
> I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB I/zygote: Do partial
>   code cache collection, code=16KB, data=37KB
>
> After code cache collection, code=16KB, data=37KB
>
> Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
>
> I/zygote: JIT allocated 71KB for compiled code of void
>   android.widget.TextView.(android.content.Context,
>   android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
>
> Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void
>   android.widget.TextView.(android.content.Context,
>   android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)

Comment: Please include the specific error logs so people can help you better

Comment: Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

Comment: Can you tell me how to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)?

Comment: Hi @WenhaoGe In error log we see that an error name"Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first. "

Comment: Have you initilised it ? Where ?You have forget it?Please initialized it first.

Answer (score 0):

You need call

**`FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context);`**

before

`db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();`

Comment: Hello@jackz314, I already added FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context); in the onCreate() method in SecondActivity before db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(); But the app is still not working correctly. Same problem remains. Can you help me solve the problem?                                                                                          
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second2);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }

Answer (score 0):

See this explanation of [`FirebaseApp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp), I don't think it's needed to call `initializeApp` in your code like the error log suggested, unless you're using a different Firebase project. I think the problem is either in your program's initialize process, or you have a wrong configuration for your project, for example, a wrong/corrupted `google-services.json` file, a wrong package name set up in the Firebase console, or other things that are likely to cause a problem.